# Finding ACF of MA Process

Tags: probability, statistics

trying to solve a general problem found in my textbook.

I have the following MA Process,

$X_t = \epsilon_t +0.8\epsilon_{t-1} + 0.4\epsilon_{t-12}+0.32\epsilon_{t-13} $

I simply want to calculate the autocorrelations of $X_t$ for lags k = 0 and k = 12

Here's what i've done so far:

For $K = 0$

$E(X_t\epsilon_t) = \epsilon_t^2=1$

and for $K = 12$

$E(X_t\epsilon_{t-12}) = ? $

I think I am on the right path but would appreciate anyone who can guide me to the finish line! Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe
$$\begin{align}
&\text{Cov}(X_t, X_{t+s}) = \\
&\text{Cov}(\epsilon_t+0.8\epsilon_{t-1} + 0.4\epsilon_{t-12} + 0.32\epsilon_{t-13}, \epsilon_{t+s}+0.8\epsilon_{t+s-1} + 0.4\epsilon_{t+s-12} + 0.32\epsilon_{t+s-13})\text{.}
\end{align}$$
We make use of the fact that the $\epsilon_t$ are uncorrelated, so that the only way you would have a non-zero autocovariance is if $s$ is chosen so that one of the subscripts of the $\epsilon$ terms of $X_{t+s}$ matches one of $X_t$.

Start by looking at $\epsilon_{t+s}$ and seeing what values of $s$ yield a term in $X_t$.

If $s = 0$, assuming that the white noise $\epsilon_t$ has variance $\sigma^2$, we obtain
$$\text{Cov}(X_t, X_t) = \text{Var}(X_t) =  \sigma^2+0.8^2\sigma^2+0.4^2\sigma^2+0.32^2\sigma^2=1.9024\sigma^2\text{.}$$
If $s = -1$, we have
$$\text{Cov}(X_t, X_{t-1})  = \text{Cov}(0.8\epsilon_{t-1} +0.32\epsilon_{t-13}, \epsilon_{t-1} + 0.4\epsilon_{t-13})$$
(you should be able to see why these are the only two terms that matter in $X_t$ and $X_{t-1}$ - if you have to do the intermediate work to see this, you will take too long to solve these problems) yielding
$$\text{Cov}(X_t, X_{t-1}) = 0.8\text{Cov}(\epsilon_{t-1}, \epsilon_{t-1}) + 0.32 \cdot 0.4\text{Cov}(\epsilon_{t-13}, \epsilon_{t-13}) = 0.928\sigma^2\text{.}$$
If $s = -12$, you have
$$\text{Cov}(X_t, X_{t-12}) = \text{Cov}(0.4\epsilon_{t-12}, \epsilon_{t-12}) = 0.4\sigma^2\text{.}$$
If $s = -13$, you have
$$\text{Cov}(X_t, X_{t-13}) = \text{Cov}(0.32\epsilon_{t-13}, \epsilon_{t-13}) = 0.32\sigma^2\text{.}$$
Now look at $\epsilon_{t+s-1}$. For $s = 1$, we obtain
$$\text{Cov}(X_t, X_{t+1}) = \text{Cov}(\epsilon_t + 0.4\epsilon_{t-12}, 0.8\epsilon_{t} + 0.32\epsilon_{t-12}) = (0.8 + 0.32 \cdot 0.4)\sigma^2 = 0.928\sigma^2\text{.}$$
The case $s = 0$ has already been covered.

For $s = -11$, we have
$$\text{Cov}(X_t, X_{t-11}) = \text{Cov}(0.4\epsilon_{t-12}, 0.8\epsilon_{t-12}) = 0.32\sigma^2\text{.}$$

We've already covered $s = -12$.

Now we proceed to $\epsilon_{t+s-12}$.

For $s = 12$, we have $0.4\sigma^2$.

For $s = 11$, we have $0.32\sigma^2$.

The case $s = 0$ has already been covered, as has $s = -1$.

Lastly, for $\epsilon_{t+s-13}$ - for $s = 13$, we have $0.32\sigma^2$.

We've already covered $s = 12$, $s = 1$, and $s = 0$.

Thus we are finished, and the autocovariance function is given by
$$\gamma_x(s) = \sigma^2 \cdot \begin{cases}
1.9024, & s = 0 \\
0.928, & s = \pm 1 \\
0.32, & s = \pm 11 \\
0.4, & s = \pm 12  \\
0.32, & s = \pm 13 \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Finally got my head around it now :)